# Thread-safe std::string and std::stringbuf in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, stl, thread-safety

In my multithread C++ program on Solaris 10 using GNU 2.95.3, I am getting a contention issue while one thread is trying to call the string constructor and other thread is calling a stringbuf constructor, as mentioned below:
One thread is calling

```
__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0PCc
```

i.e.

```
basic_string<char, string_char_traits<char>, __default_alloc_template<false, 0>>::basic_string(char const *)
```

Another thread is calling

```
__9stringbufRCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0i
```

i.e.

```
stringbuf::stringbuf(basic_string<char, string_char_traits<char>, __default_alloc_template<false, 0> > const &, int)
```

Eventually both threads lead to allocating space for the string or stringbuf as applicable and results in a contention leading to SIGBUS error.
Any clue?
Do I need to overload malloc or new to be thread-safe or do I need to overload string and stringbuf to ensure thread safety?
I use g++ linker flag as below:
I `g++ -g -lclntsh -ldl -lsocket -lrt –lthread`
Do I need to add '`g++ -pthread`' during compilation? I hope this would add -D_RENENTRANT as well. But Solaris g++ 2.95.3 does not support -pthread

Here's more pstack core output:

```
core 'core' of 28477:   
-----------------  lwp# 1 / thread# 1  --------------------
 fcb48ac4 __lwp_park (0, 0, fcbb74c4, 1c00, 0, 0) + 14
 ff375244 sem_wait (1da56fd8, 1da56c00, 8ea400, 2aae33d0, fcbb49cc, 0) + 20
....
 001965f0 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 5c
-----------------  lwp# 2 / thread# 2  --------------------
 fcb4c714 _lwp_kill (a, fed84948, 0, 1, fffffffc, 0) + 8
 fdfd6c6c skgesigOSCrash (fc3eea54, fc3ee8fc, ff031460, fef7536c, bc0f4, bc000) + 4c
 fe5253a0 kpeDbgSignalHandler (fc3eea54, 2b200cd8, 9e800, a, fc3eee5d, 6060000) + 2f0
 fdfd71ac skgesig_sigactionHandler (a, fc3ef6e0, fefef8f8, 0, ff0314a0, fc3eea40) + f0
 fcb48b4c __sighndlr (a, fc3ef6e0, fc3ef428, fdfd70bc, 0, 1) + c
 fcb3d1f8 call_user_handler (a, 0, 8, 0, fc540200, fc3ef428) + 3b8
 fcb3d3cc sigacthandler (a, fc3ef6e0, fc3ef428, 1, fc540200, 0) + 4c
 --- called from signal handler with signal 10 (SIGBUS) ---
 00608e00 allocate__t24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Ui (20, 20, 9eff80, 1c7be, 2ab11e06, fcbb4f18) +
 a4
 003cde3c __nw__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0_3RepU
iUi (10, 10, ff000000, 4, fc540200, 861908) + 14
 003cef8c create__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0_3Re
pUi (2, 2, 2b10d5c8, fcbb5434, fcbb5784, fffc00) + 24
 003ee944 replace__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0UiUiP
CcUi (fc3efaf8, 0, ffffffff, 8618a0, 2, 80808080) + 114
 006919cc assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0PCcUi
(fc3efaf8, 8618a0, 2, 0, fc540200, 7164b4) + 24
 00666684 assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0PCc (f
c3efaf8, 8618a0, 8ea400, 0, fc5706c0, 0) + 24
 005f7868 __t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0PCc (fc3efaf
8, 8618a0, 861800, 0, fc3efa90, a4090) + 28
....
-----------------  lwp# 3 / thread# 3  --------------------
 fcb41818 mutex_lock_impl (fcbb3910, 0, 2dfc0030, fc3beee0, 6, 80808080) + 4
 fcad640c malloc   (6, 1, d9fd8, 6919cc, fcbb03a8, fcbba518) + 44
 003c878c __builtin_vec_new (6, 3, 37, fc3bee38, ff32a888, 4) + 3c
 005e16ec __9stringbufRCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0
i (fc3bee60, fc3bee58, 3, 0, 2b2ab6e8, 20) + 64
...
-----------------  lwp# 4 / thread# 4  --------------------
 fcb48ac4 __lwp_park (0, 0, fcbb74c4, 1c00, 0, 0) + 14
 ff375244 sem_wait (1da56f48, 1da56c00, 1, 0, fc541200, 0) + 20
....
 fcb48a20 _lwp_start (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: yes @deviantfan, that's what 'pstack core' reveals, this is for Solaris 10 using GNU gcc/g++ compiler 2.95.3

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana Isn't 2.95.3. about 15 years old...? Well, could you show how you call the compiler too? (do you know stuff like -D_REENTRANT etc.?)

Comment: @deviantfan yes it's pretty old, I compile as: g++ -g -lclntsh -ldl -lsocket -lrt

Comment: @deviantfan, Do I need to add '`g++ -pthread`' during compilation? I hope this would add -D_RENENTRANT as well.

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana Yes, `-pthread` includes `-D_REENTRANT` (and the linking option for the actual library). At least it does on new versions, not sure about yours. (Attention REENTRANT, not RENENTRANT)

Comment: @deviantfan, my g++ 2.95.3 says: g++: unrecognized option `-pthread'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94691/discussion-between-deviantfan-and-dr-debasish-jana).

Comment: Please post your `pstack` output.

Comment: @AndrewHenle edited my original post with more psatck info

Comment: Only recent versions of GCC support `-pthread` on Solaris. Older versions supported `-pthreads` instead, but 2.95 might be too old even for that, so you would need `-D_REENTRANT` and `-lpthread` or `-lthread` instead.

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana You might be getting heap corruption.  Try `LD_PRELOAD=watchmalloc.so.1 MALLOC_DEBUG=WATCH,RW ./a.out`, where `a.out` is your compiled binary.  That will run **slow**, but it stands a good chance of finding any heap corruption that may be causing your `SIGBUS`.  Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5168/6mbb3hs40/index.html  Example:  https://blogs.oracle.com/wfiveash/entry/playing_with_solaris_memory_debuggers